# Unable to start Kestrel with System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint

Tags: docker, cmd, docker-compose, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to build the docker image for the .NET Core 2.2 web application by using this command

> > docker-compose -f docker-compose.override.yml -f docker-compose.yml up --build

But I am getting the below error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
> demo  |       User profile is available. Using '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
> demo  | crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
> demo  |       Unable to start Kestrel.
> demo  | System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found.
> demo  | To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
> demo  | For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
> demo  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions) demo  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions) demo  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context) demo  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
> demo  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken) demo  | demo  | Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found. demo  | To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'. demo  | For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054. demo  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
> demo  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
> demo  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
> demo  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding) demo  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> demo  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> demo  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
> demo  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
> demo  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)

I did some R & D on google to fix the above issue by following steps: But there is no luck.

> **dotnet dev-certs https --check --verbose**
>
> A valid certificate was found.
>
> **dotnet dev-certs https**
>
> A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.
>
> **dotnet dev-certs https --trust**
>
> Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. If the
> certificate is not already trusted we will run the following command:
> 'sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k
> /Library/Keychains/System.keychain <>' This command might
> prompt you for your password to install the certificate on the system
> keychain. A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.

Note: I have deleted the present certificate from **certmgr**.  And then run the same above commands but there is no use.

So, can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find an answer?